# How can I calculate the sum of the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to calculate the sum of S=(1-1/2 +1/3-1/4+...). I used wolfram Alpha but the answer makes no sense to me.

[image: Answer from Wolfram Alpha]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks!